# Issue in a while loop with my BufferedReader

Tags: java

I've a little issue with my `script` function.

To set the context, I want to create a loop so that it modifies a text document little by little, in relation to what the user enters in the console.

My text document is written so that several "INSERT" entries are listed, and the user can replace them two by two with the text of his choice.

But the problem is the following: the String arraylist `content` remains empty, that logically causes an error on the 16th line, because there is a problem with the BufferedReader (the String `line` is systematically null, because of a Strem error).

How can I solve this ?
The code is the following :

```
public void script() {
    while(index*5 <= array.size()) {
        List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
        int modificater = 1;
        int position = (((index-1)*5)+4);
        
        FileInputStream fIS= new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIS, "UTF-8"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        
        while(line != null) {
            content.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println(content.get(position - 1));
        Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = enter.nextLine();
        
        while(modificater < 3) {
            for(String str : content) {
                if(str.contains("INSERT")) {
                    str.replace("INSERT", answer);
                    modificater++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        reader.close();
        
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                            
        for(String str : content) {
            bw.write(str);
            bw.newLine();
        }

        writer.close();
        index++;
    }
}
```

Here is an error that I have :

````
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:51)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:124)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:208)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:268)```
````

Comment: Please show the full exception stacktrace, and I recommend you learn about try-with-resources. The problem will go away when you use that, and also when you close `bw` instead of `writer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your reader below your writer.close() and close your bw.

```
public void script() {
while(index*5 <= array.size()) {
    List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
    int modificater = 1;
    int position = (((index-1)*5)+4);
    
    FileInputStream fIS= new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIS, "UTF-8"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    
    while(line != null) {
        content.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    System.out.println(content.get(position - 1));
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = enter.nextLine();
    
    while(modificater < 3) {
        for(String str : content) {
            if(str.contains("INSERT")) {
                str.replace("INSERT", answer);
                modificater++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                        
    for(String str : content) {
        bw.write(str);
        bw.newLine();
    }

    reader.close();
    bw.close();
    writer.close();
    index++;
}
```

}

Comment: Lots of things in a loop there that shouldn't be. First thing that comes to mind is the creation of a `Scanner` on `System.in` Bear in mind also that the output file will only contain what happened on the last iteration as it's not appending, but overwriting